# TikZ : matrix nodes name unknown after update

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I just upgraded from fedora version 32 to version 33. Tikz has therefore been updated (from the 3.1.4b to 3.1.5b). Since this change, this figure no longer compiles (I uses Lualatex) :

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{RdBu-9-1}{RGB}{178,24,43}
\definecolor{RdBu-9-2}{RGB}{214,96,77}
\definecolor{RdBu-9-8}{RGB}{67,147,195}
\definecolor{RdBu-9-9}{RGB}{33,102,172}

\usepackage{tikz}  
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzset{%
  ffa/.style={%
    pattern=north west lines,
    pattern color=RdBu-9-2, 
    draw=none
  },
  ffc/.style={%
    draw=RdBu-9-1, 
    line width=1}
}

\usepackage[babel, autostyle]{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix [matrix of nodes,
  anchor=west,
  nodes={minimum size=.75cm}
  ] (zla0) at (0,0)
  {
    \draw[ffa,ffc] (0,0) circle (.3cm);&
    \draw[ffa,ffc] (0,0) circle (.3cm);\\
  };

  \matrix [matrix of nodes,
  anchor=north,
  nodes={minimum size=.75cm},
  below=2cm of zla0] (zlb0)
  {
    \draw[ffa,ffc] (0,0) circle (.3cm);\\
  };

  \foreach \m in {0} {
    \draw (zla\m.south west) |- ($(zla\m.south west)!0.5!(zla\m.south
    east) + (0,-.1)$) -| (zla\m.south east)  node[pos=0, yshift=.2]
    (zla\m-g) {};
    % 
    \draw (zlb\m.north west) |- ($(zlb\m.north west)!0.5!(zlb\m.north
    east) + (0,.1)$) -| (zlb\m.north east)  node[pos=0, yshift=.2]
    (zlb\m-g) {};
    % 
    \draw[->>, black,] ([yshift=-.2cm]zla\m.south) -- ([yshift=.2cm]zlb\m.north);
  }

  \draw[|-, black] ([yshift=1.25cm]zla0-1-2.north) -- (zla0-1-2.north)
  node[pos=.6,fill=white, minimum size=.75cm]{};

  \node[above=0cm of zla0-1-1.north, anchor=south, align=center,
  font=\tiny, text width=1.75cm]{\enquote{Je suis proche du \emph{Pic
        Jean Ray}}};

  \node[above=1.25cm of zla0-1-2.north, anchor=south, align=center,
  font=\tiny, text width=1.75cm]{\enquote{Je suis sous une \emph{crête}}};

  \node[below=0cm of zlb0.south, anchor=north, align=center,
  font=\tiny, text width=4cm]{\enquote{Je suis proche du \emph{Pic
        Jean Ray} et sous une crête}};

  \node[fill=white,align=center, font=\large\sffamily] at ($(zla0.south east)!0.5!(zlb0.north
  west)$){\emph{Fusion} des \emph{indices de localisation}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

At compilation I get errors like :

```
ERROR: Package pgf Error: No shape named `zla0-1-2' is known.
```

By searching in the tikz repository I have identified the problem: the cells of a `matrix of nodes` that contain a `\path` derivative (like `\draw`) are directly treated and not added to a `node` ([source](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/13166d154e90375ce8c2752461b7bd20950c6098/doc/generic/pgf/text-en/pgfmanual-en-library-matrices.tex#L100)). But I haven't found out why this code, which worked on ferora 32, doesn't work anymore (I couldn't find any information in the tikz [changelog](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/a3e86f8526789fa484ee09b10bdfa583c19fc167/doc/generic/pgf/ChangeLog#L1077) or anything else).

What is the best solution to make this figure work again? Knowing that I have several figures that are built on this scheme (this one is the simplest, for the example) and that I have few time to make these modifications.

The best would be if there was an option to switch to the old way of working, but I haven't found anything similar in the documentation.

Ps : I have ask the same question in french [here](https://texnique.fr/osqa/questions/9449/tikz-identifiants-des-cellules-dune-matrice-invalides-apres-mise-a-jour), if I have an answer there I would post here and vice versa.

Comment: This different-from-document behavior was introduced by [`b9750809`](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/commit/b9750809) and restored by [`5e2f4a88`](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/commit/5e2f4a88), and the influenced tikz releases are 3.1.2 to 3.1.4b (inclusive).

Comment: Though nesting `tikzpicture` is not officially supported, adding `\tikz` before every `\draw` used in matrix cells seems to work. BTW, to make `\tiny` defined, you need, for example, document class `article`.

Comment: Indeed my *minimal example* is too minimal. In the whole document I uses the `scrbook` class with some customizations.

I tried to add the `tikz` command before each `draw` and it works very well, thanks. The result is not exactly the same (the rows are a bit thicker), but this is not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cells in TikZ matrices that aren't just a node don't have name. (Even nodes that are put in cells of `matrix of nodes` with `\node` don't have a name unless you give them one.)

Besides using actual nodes like that

```
\matrix [
  matrix of nodes,
  anchor=west,
  nodes in empty cells,
  nodes={ffa, ffc, circle, minimum size=.6cm}
] (zla0) at (0,0) { & \\};
```

which would put the same circle into the cell as your `\draw` you can let TikZ install a tight rectangular node around each cell's bounding box. You still won't be able to reference the actual elements inside the cell, of course. (Unless they're nodes and you give them names.)

The `install fitted node at end cell` key will install the necessary `\node` at the end of every cell. The `\path[every node/.code]` part makes sure we don't inherit any styles from the `every node` key. These nodes are named `<matrix name>-<row>-<column>'` (note the `'`) so that there's no conflict with actual nodes in a `matrix of node`.

I've also tried giving the `current bounding box` an alias or install a `local bounding box` for every cell but these all need more work because actual nodes (that shall be used later) need to be installed in a special matrix hook so that their position is known after the matrix – and even then the line-width wasn't considered.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\definecolor{RdBu-9-1}{RGB}{178,24,43}
\definecolor{RdBu-9-2}{RGB}{214,96,77}
\definecolor{RdBu-9-8}{RGB}{67,147,195}
\definecolor{RdBu-9-9}{RGB}{33,102,172}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, calc, positioning, arrows, matrix, fit}
\tikzset{% This is the new key.
  install fitted node at end cell/.style={
    execute at end cell={%
      \path[every node/.code=] node[shape=rectangle, fit=(current bounding box),
        inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt, name=\tikzmatrixname-%
          \the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn']{};}}}
\tikzset{
  ffa/.style={pattern=north west lines, pattern color=RdBu-9-2,  draw=none},
  ffc/.style={draw=RdBu-9-1, line width=1}}
\usepackage[babel, autostyle]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[radius=.3cm]
\matrix [
  install fitted node at end cell, % ← Here's the new key used.
  anchor=west] (zla0) at (0,0) {
  \draw[ffa,ffc] (0,0) circle []; &
  \draw[ffa,ffc] (0,0) circle []; \\};
\matrix [below=2cm of zla0] (zlb0) {\draw[ffa,ffc] (0,0) circle [];\\};
\foreach \m in {0} {
  \draw (zla\m.south west)
    |- ($(zla\m.south west)!0.5!(zla\m.south east) + (0,-.1)$)
    -| (zla\m.south east) node[pos=0, yshift=.2] (zla\m-g) {};
  \draw (zlb\m.north west)
    |- ($(zlb\m.north west)!0.5!(zlb\m.north east) + (0,.1)$)
    -| (zlb\m.north east)  node[pos=0, yshift=.2] (zlb\m-g) {};
  \draw[->>, black,] ([yshift=-.2cm]zla\m.south) -- ([yshift=.2cm]zlb\m.north);
}
\draw[|-, black] ([yshift=1.25cm]zla0-1-2'.north) -- (zla0-1-2')
  node[pos=.6,fill=white, minimum size=.75cm]{};
\node[above=0cm of zla0-1-1'.north, anchor=south, align=center, font=\tiny,
  text width=1.75cm]{\enquote{Je suis proche du \emph{Pic Jean Ray}}};
\node[above=1.25cm of zla0-1-2'.north, anchor=south, align=center, font=\tiny,
  text width=1.75cm]{\enquote{Je suis sous une \emph{crête}}};
\node[below=0cm of zlb0.south, anchor=north, align=center, font=\tiny,
  text width=4cm]{
    \enquote{Je suis proche du \emph{Pic Jean Ray} et sous une crête}};
\node[fill=white, align=center, font=\large\sffamily]
  at ($(zla0.south east)!0.5!(zlb0.north west)$)
  {\emph{Fusion} des \emph{indices de localisation}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]